# url structure is not working well in magento site with categories and sub categories

Tags: category, url, menu

we used following format under " age" menu in [Current Demo URL][2]

code  : [PASTEBIN DEMO][3]

**"shop by age "**is main category and all other are sub category.

but urls are generating like as in the image

> shop-by-age/shop-by-age/shop-by-age/shop-by-age/0-6-months.html

click on **0-6 months for 3 or 4 times**

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the links are generated in this menu is wrong.

The href attribute is using relative path whereas it should use absolute path.

Adding slashes at the beginning of the href attributes will fix it.

Your final code should look like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/0-6-months.html">0-6 Months</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/6-months-and-above.html">6 Months and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/1-year-and-above.html">1 Year and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/2-years-and-above.html">2 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/3-years-and-above.html">3 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/4-years-and-above.html">4 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/5-years-and-above.html">5 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/6-years-and-above.html">6 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/7-years-and-above.html">7 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/8-years-and-above.html">8 Years and above</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop-by-age/10-years-and-above.html">10 Years and above</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: is it better to give category url path to sub category url or leaving category url is better?

which is better in following:

<li><a href="/shop-by-age/0-6-months.html">0-6 Months</a></li> or         this one : 
<li><a href="/0-6-months.html">0-6 Months</a></li>

Comment: Definitely the first one as the second one suggests that all subcategories are also defined as top categories which (except if you create them and didn't display them in the menu) is not true in your case.